# Using R Jug, Post works but cannot use Get for functions

Tags: r, api, curl

I am trying to use the jug package in R, and with the following code am able to use Post to get the following response:

```
say_hello<-function(name){paste("hello",name,"!")}

jug() %>%
  post("/hello", decorate(say_hello)) %>%
  serve_it()

#$ curl -s --data "name=Bart" http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello
###returns hello Bart !
```

However, when I use GET (exactly like https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jug/vignettes/jug.html), I get a error as below. I've tried different permutations of GET syntax, but cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

```
jug() %>%
  get("/", decorate(say_hello)) %>%
  serve_it()
#$ curl 127.0.0.1:8080/?name=Bart
###returns "ERROR: Request not handled or no body set by any middleware"
```